# I can't install Android Studio in Windows 8

Tags: android, android-studio

I need to install Android Studio in windows 8, but I can not because during the installation tells me it can not find the JDK installation, create the variable HOME_JAVA and truth and not able to continue with the installation.

someone tried to run it in Windows 8?

Comment: http://commonsware.com/blog/2013/05/16/android-studio-early-access-preview-and-you.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, I did, and find out why it didnt worked!
Go to your system variables, and simply remove the "/bin" from JAVA_HOME or JDK_HOME.

Answer (score 0):

Do you have java jdk in your system.
if not try installing http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/index.html

I will suggest you to update your windows 10 is a lot more better then 8 
if you are developer you should keep your things updated.