# Android Studio start fails on Windows 8 64bit

Tags: android, windows, android-studio

Installation works fine, JDK was also found without problems. After installation the program does not start. Double clicking the icon results in nothing happening. Starting as admin or installing "just for me" or for all users makes no difference. 
I am out of answers.. Is this maybe a common issue?

Comment: Did you use the search? Check [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16594726/i-cant-install-android-studio-in-winodws-8), [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16580657/android-studio-does-not-run), and [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16583120/android-studio-not-loading/16583198#16583198) to start.

Comment: We're aware of the issue and working on it. I've added a Known Issue and a workaround here yesterday in the meantime: http://tools.android.com/knownissues#as0.1

Comment: You need to set your JAVA_HOME env variable and append %JAVA_HOME%\bin to your PATH env variable!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

After download and install Java SE Development Kit 7 - `"jdk-7u21-windows-x64.exe"` from [Oracle site](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/jdk8-downloads-2133151.html)
then adds `JAVA_HOME (value = c:\program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_21)` to environment variables. It works fine with me on Windows 8.

Answer (score 4):

**the solution** is so simply
**by:**
Adding a system variable 
`JDK_HOME`

with value `c:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_21\` worked for me.

Latest Java release can be downloaded [here](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/jdk7-downloads-1880260.html).

Answer (score 3):

Go to

> control panel -> System -> Advance system settings -> Environment
>   variable

Then, under system variable click new, enter variable name `JDK_HOME` and variable value `C:\programfiles\java\jdk` (this path can be different on different computer.)

Then restart android studio.

Answer (score 0):

I had this on windows 7 64 bit.  I needed to manually set my JAVA_HOME environment variable.  Try that, and try running it from a command shell so you can see the exact error.

Answer (score 0):

Here's an existing thread that has a bit more detail on this. As of today, you probably have the same version of Java as the answer, so you could just copy and paste and be on your way in no time.

[Android Studio does not launch after installation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16574544/android-studio-does-not-launch-after-installation)