# Android studio is not starting in windows 8, jdk installed and environmental variable set

Tags: android, android-studio, java, java-7

my android studio is not starting, i am not getting any error messages, environmental variable is set and JDK is installed

Answer (score 0):

Have you set your enviroment variable correct? 
If not add in

```
Control panel -> System -> Advance system settings -> Environment variable: 
      JAVA_HOME (value = c:\program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_21))
```

Further more, have you looked at these [topics](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16596520/android-studio-start-fails-on-windows-8-64bit)? Problems with Android Studio are discussed detailed here and most are caused by an incorrect enviroment variable.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you set your **PATH** variable and append **%JAVA_HOME%\bin** to it.

Answer (score 0):

When you type download android studio in widows and if your environment variable is not set then you cant install it. First you need to set environment variable. Follow below instructions:

1. Confirm that PATH is not set for Java by typing javac in command prompt.
   Open Control Panel and Select System and Security
2. Select System
3. Select Advanced System Settings
4. Select Environment Variables
5. Select and Edit Path Environment variable just paste the jdk path after ":" and also end with ":"
6. Verify Java path by typing javac in command prompt

Now you can download android Studio set up and can start development.

Answer (score 0):

Just try to change your JDK version.Degrade the version and then try to set the PATH and JAVA_HOME System variables.