# Failing to install android studio on windows 8.1

Tags: android

[image]I have downloaded the android studio exe file several times and while installing it gives an error enter image description here
[image]

I have tried it several times but i don't know what is the problem.Can't we use android studios in windows 8.1? All my dev work is really stuck.. please help

Comment: Have you tried to run the installer as administrator?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16596520/android-studio-start-fails-on-windows-8-64bit

Comment: yes I have done it as an administrator as well. But it doesn't work.

Comment: I am able to install it, but while starting the android studio it gives me this error

Comment: Are you able to open the SDK Manager via console?

Comment: Error-- The following SDK component was not installed: build-tools-21.1.1

Comment: @ A Honey Bustard, can you elaborate a bit?

Comment: Do i need to install the SDK components separately?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17963508/how-to-install-android-sdk-build-tools-on-the-command-line

Answer (score 0):

You should try and install Android SDK Manager first.
Run it as Administrator and download the latest Build Tools.
Then install Android Studio and provide the location of your android sdk 
folder during or after install.

Comment: while installation i am getting an error window saying : Failed to install Intel HAXM. For details, please check the installation log:
"c:\Users\Rahul\AppData\Local\Temp\nsnEE4A.tmp\haxm_silent_run.log". I am not sure does that mean.. Using eclipse for android development was way better than this.

Comment: From what I can tell the Intel Haxam speeds up your app emulation while using the Android Studio AVD. You should use genymotion for testing your app, is way faster. Also if Android Studio is not working after this, you should do a clean install and without the AVD included in the options.

Comment: I downloaded android studios from https://developer.android.com/sdk/index.html. It goes up to 95% and then gives me this HAXM error. Then I click on ignore or skip. And when the installation is finished and when I start the android studios I see the error that I have mentioned in the screens above. I have not yet got an option to include the AVD or not. I am running a windows 8.1 machine, can that be a problem? I am really frustrated with this.

Comment: Has your PC virtualization? Is it enabled in the bios? (the HAXM error seems quite weird to me)

Comment: Ok, so I completed the installation, android studios works. But while running an application the system gives me an error the AVD cannot be launched because intel HAXM was not installed. When I am trying to install Intell HAXM from the android studios package, it gives me an error. Any help on this would be appreciated.

Comment: Run the Android SDK Manager as Administrator and download the desired package.